# Why am I unable to play the newest version of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I have an Mac OS X Yosemite computer and I've been wanting to play the newest version of Minecraft. Any time I try to open a version of 1.13 or higher, it gives me the exit code 0.

I have little to no technology knowledge but I do have the newest version of Java. Even if i try to play 1.13 it gives me exit code 0. I don't know why this is happening or what I could do to fix it.

Comment: Can you post a link to the crash log file? We can't really help you without the log.

Comment: Exit code 0 usually signifies that something closed properly. Odd. maybe its different for Minecraft idk

Comment: Do you have java8 or 11, use 8 if you have 11.